# Invalid external type library references ("Error loading DLL")

Tags: visual-c++, vb6, typelib

Whilst I am doing VB6 development, I think that this is a wider issue. I have found that sometimes in the VB IDE we get an error: [BadImplementsRefInCompatLib]. Using the Type Library Viewer that comes with "Advanced Visual Basic 6" by Matt Curland, it flags up that the type library in my component has a reference to a type library it can't find, but not what it is. The underlying error is with the TLI component when it tries to find out about an interface that is defined in another type library.

I also tried OLE View - to try and reverse compile the IDL - but again, it gave an error message when trying to get the external type, without identifying the erroneous value.

I traced the actual error back to the type library reference in the registry which was point to a component, but the major version was incorrect. Replacing the major version fixed the issue.

I used a binary editor to see if I could spot what information is being used in the type library. And indeed, I found the names (no paths) of the components which it references, but I couldn't work out the format. I was actually hoping to find a table of type library GUIDs and version numbers. I suppose I could write code to extract these names, and eliminate the "working" references, but this is a bit crude.

Does anyone know how a type library references external types?

Comment: Type libraries have a version number for a good reason.  You can edit this problem away but that just produces undiagnosable failure at runtime when you call a procedure that was changed.  Only obtaining and registering the correct type library is the solution.

Comment: @HansPassant - I fully understand the point of the versioning the type library. Unfortunately, the behaviour of the TLI component is not very helpful - it raises an error without providing some form of information about *why* it couldn't resolve the reference so I can take appropriate action. At the moment, I have to guess why it hasn't worked!

Answer (score 2):

`[BadImplementsRefInCompatLib]` means that your binary compatible target's typelib has a reference to an external typelib and this external typelib is not registered.

For instance if you have a project group with several ActiveX DLLs that are set to binary compatible version compatibility **and** `Project2` references `Project1` (uses types from Project1 on functions/properties prototypes of a public class) when `Project1` breaks compatibility and gets recompiled `Project2`'s compatibility target has a typelib that references external typelib that is not registered (namely the old version of `Project1` component).

In our shop we do have references across VB6 projects but never ever use types from core on public methods/properties of classes. Such parameters are declared `As Object` and down-cast in code which is less trouble than tying components with external cross references. Curland's `EditTLB` is used regularly to spot offending classes.

No idea how a type library references external types. I just `importlib("component.tlb")` in idl and use types from `component` at will.

Btw, a very simple way to "protect" a COM component (DLL/OCX) from being used in VB6 IDE is to reference a `struct` in external custom made typelib (param to a public method) and then "forget" to ship this external typelib. VB6 IDE chokes with "Error loading DLL" on adding a reference to the DLL/OCX but the component works and registers perfectly, provided you don't try to call this "obfuscated" method cross threads (in-process or not).

Comment: yeah, I got the general gist of that from my own experiments. Unfortunately, I am working with code from over 10 years of development, and there are 150+ components, all of which have cross-dependencies. It's interesting to see that your shop has essentially given up using your own types on public interfaces. In retrospect, that's what should have been done with the code I am working with. However, I am stuck with what I've got, and it would be nice to have a way of tracing back the chain of dependencies for these kind of development-only errors and fix them easily.

Comment: How do you compile these 150+ components? You have to topolically sort these on their cross-dependencies, so you have to keep these references documented. If you have a build server devs should never need to compile components on their machines (if they need then just start the build on the server). We keep vbp's in project compatibility on dev machines, and never get `[BadImplements]`. The IDE gets so much more responsive in project compatibility too.

Comment: We use Nant to build these components. And yes, we had to sort out all of the dependencies. The only thing we don't do is to use project compatibility on dev machines. To be quite honest, I thought this was only important for when compiling components. Does using project compatibility in project run-time essentially tell the IDE to "fix uo" all the references?

Comment: In project compatibility IDE just check typelib ID, does not inspect or care about class IDs or interface IDs so compatibility target's lib GUID is the only thing read, nothing is matched against project's current source code. So compile in IDE gets much faster, including background compile (for intellisense) which happens on source navigation in IDE (on entering space too). Binary compatibility often chokes with "out of memory" if dependent components public classes are modified in IDE sometimes.